# Showing volume control for embedded MediaPlayer video?

Tags: html, video, controls, media-player

I would think there would be a simple param for embedded videos to show a volume control but I cannot seem to find anything except stuff on controlling the systems volume using jquery. Is there a way to just enable the built in volume control of an embedded video?

If I use this code to embed the video is there a way to enable the volume control of the player?

```
<object CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="220">
<param name="fileName" value="URL of my Video">
<param name="autoStart" value="false">
<param name="showControls" value="true">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="URL of my video" width=220 autoStart=0 showcontrols=1>
</object>
```

Comment: As a suggestion, your question (and the tags you use) should mention the problem domain.  This looks like HTML so it should get the "html" tag, and the question is certainly specific to Media Player rather than, say, flash video.  I've edited the title and tags to make it clearer.

Comment: Not that I have any room to argue (seeing as I misspelled embedded more than once) but I figured those tags were most relevant because that is specifically what I want to know. Anyways If you think that the changes you made are better suited then that's fine and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is. and apparently you added it for two players. i dunno whether the parametes are correct, but this embedding teqnique is really out of date and will not be supported for as many clients as video could be.

you should check out the html5 video tag, the next best alternative (imo) is flash.

have a look at this article: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

Comment: So if I did it using the HTML5 video tag I would need to convert the video from avi to ogg AND mp4? That article also shows a swf file but I do not want to use flash because when I tried to use flash I kept running into problems. Is that necessary? Is it really that big of a deal if I want to leave the video embedded the way it is? If not do you know how to activate the volume controls? What is the advantage to using HTML5 VS directly embedding a video like I have?

Comment: you are not directly embedding a video file. you are relying on an external plugin (in fact you are using two). html5 would be directly embedding. please check the references for your plugins at http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_playerref.asp and http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-media-player and do whatever you think is best for your situation

Comment: I got it done. I am using the video tag now. It is working Thanks.